# Is there a place to ask SEO questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site already for SEO questions or is this maybe a subject I should take to Area 51?

This company has a site for virtually every other computing discipline, but I don't seem to see a place where SEO questions can be asked. Is it maybe on-topic at the [Webmasters site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: How about you read the [/help/on-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of the webmasters site? Pay some extra attention to the first bullit.

Answer (score 5):

Search Engine Optimization questions are explicitly on-topic on Webmasters.

If we take a look at [their help center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Pro Webmasters is a site for asking questions about operating and managing your own website. Questions here are commonly about, but not limited to:
>
> - **Search engine optimization (SEO)**
> - Domains
> - Web and email hosting
> - Internet marketing
> - Website management (e.g., analytics, ads, URLs, etc…)

Comment: ok, thank you. I thought this topic is important enough to have it's own site. SEO is a whole computing profession and only tangentially associated with webmasters.